# Does the Meta.SE header get updated when each site comes out of beta?

Tags: support, design, meta

The Meta Stack Exchange header background seems to have the logos of many graduated sites in it.

[image: Meta.SE header]

After a quick count, you will find that there is the same number of logos in the header as there are graduated sites (minus the StackOverflows for different languages) (see the footer to count).

So, my question is: **Do site logos get added to the Meta Stack Exchange header when they are graduated and their custom design is completed?**

Comment: *"you will find that there is the same number of logos in the header as there are graduated sites"* - May I ask how you determined the number of graduated sites? Because at the moment there are logos of graduated sites missing.

Comment: @ChristianRau I checked the footer, read the graduated sites in area51, and counted the graduated sites only at http://stackexchange.com/sites#name. Then I averaged and made account for the different SO's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the logo got updated when beta-sites graduate as can be seen from this logo:

[image: meta on may 15th, 2014]

which was obtained from the [Wayback machine on May, 15th 2014](http://web.archive.org/web/20140515125731/https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

With the introduction of the redesign (responsive, left nav) which mandated a design that was generalized with less customization the MSE topbar went into a static background:

[image]

Comment: True, though I wonder how much bacon it costs them. (it's a known fact that Jin gets his salary in bacon)

Comment: Chemistry and biology graduated recently and I don't see their logos yet. So perhaps the head banner has not been revised yet.

Comment: hmm.. so this is like one of those "spot the 5 differences between these two almost exact same photos" game ... Much harder with no red freehand circles...